# How to extend boot disk ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-storage

we created a instance with 10GB of storage and loaded a few app now our PostgreSQL SQL won't start because of low disk space.

We tried to edit the instance by changing the boot disk space from 10 - 30 GB

We added a new disk 200GB

How can we  extend the boot disk sba1 (10GB)?

Comment: move postgres data directory to a new disk. if it is down - you can perform cold copy

Answer (score 0):

Off: I think you mistagged your question, it's not related to Postgres itself.

Also, you don't provided enough info about your environment (what's your filesystem? are you using lvm?)

To solve your problem without manipulating partitions you can move postgres data to your new disk partition and make a symbolic link to it:

```
mv /path/to/data/ /new/disk/
ln -s /new/disk/data /path/to/data
```